# Big data structure

Tags: bigdata

Explain the code below in a step-by-step manner. Also explain what the two join statements intend to achieve.

emp = [(1,"Smith",-1,"2018","10","M",3000), \

```
(2,"Rose",1,"2010","20","M",4000), \

(3,"Williams",1,"2010","10","M",1000), \

(4,"Jones",2,"2005","10","F",2000), \
```

]

empColumns = ["emp_id","name","superior_emp_id","year_joined", \

```
   "emp_dept_id","gender","salary"]
```

empDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=emp, schema = empColumns)

empDF.printSchema()

empDF.show(truncate=False)

dept = [("Finance",10), \

```
("Marketing",20), \

("Sales",30), \

("IT",40) \
```

]

deptColumns = ["dept_name","dept_id"]

deptDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=dept, schema = deptColumns)

deptDF.printSchema()

deptDF.show(truncate=False)

## Join statement 1

empDF.join(deptDF,empDF.emp_dept_id ==  deptDF.dept_id,"outer") \

```
.show(truncate=False)
```

## Join statement 2

empDF.join(deptDF,empDF.emp_dept_id ==  deptDF.dept_id,"right") \

.show(truncate=False)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned code is doing the following steps:

- We are creating a list named **emp** which contains list of employee data.
- Then we are creating a list named **empColumns** which has the column names for the employee data list.
- Then we are creating spark dataframe using the data in **emp** list and applying the column names on top of data.
- Further we are printing the schema of spark dataframe and printing the data in it.
- Then we are repeating the above process for department data.
- In Join Statement 1, we are performing the full outer join of the employee and department dataframes. The **outer** join keyword returns all matching records from both tables whether the other table matches or not.
- In Join Statement 2, we are performing right outer join of employee dataframe with department dataframe. The **right** join keyword returns all records from the right table (department), and the matching records from the left table (employee).

**Note:** Here `truncate=False` in dataframe show function makes sure that the data in the columns are not truncated to 20 characters which is default limit applied in pyspark show method.